# Find and Replace Count in Visual Studio 2012 not working

Tags: visual-studio-2012

The "Find and Replace" count in my Visual Studio 2012 previously worked, but somehow has turned off.

Does anyone know if this is a setting i somehow turned off?

Comment: Press Ctrl+f and it comes

Comment: Nobody can guess what you did.  My crystal ball says "Tools + Options, Environment, Find and Replace, turn on the checkboxes".

Comment: Hans to the rescue!!!!! Thank you sir.

Comment: @Hans: You should post that as an answer so it can be accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably what you are talking about:

[image]

Note the checkbox on the lower left, you probably unticked it.  Which suppresses the dialog for any future replacements.  You turn that back on with Tools + Options, Environment, Find and Replace, turn the "Display informational messages" checkbox back on.

Answer (score 1):

I guess its working, but you accidentily somehow has turn its "Match Case" sensitivity ON. So,  I would like to recommend you that go through all the options once, and try doing and undoing it, it will definitely work and all the option for F&R are available in its popup itself so you don't need to go anywhere..., if you feel it helpful, mark it as answer...